# Using a color override for representations

Tags: arcgis-9.3, representation

I'm looking for a way to automatically assign a color to a feature, mainly polylines.  I want to do this by populating a field with a value so I can link it to a color.  I believe this is possible with representation symbology, but I haven't been able to find out how to use the override field for color.  Is there a specific type of field it has to be?  Is there some format the attributes have to be, ie RGB values?  Perhaps there are other ways to do this as well?  I am open to ideas, but representation symbology is what I need the end result to be.

Comment: Do you just want to symbolize based on an attribute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Required - ArcInfo License

Must be using a Personal or File Geodatabase

http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=Managing_feature_class_representations

Create a default [subtype] representation you want to automate [See RoadType below]
Then set up a rule (creates RuleID)

Apply the Override to all other representations.

[image]

**Limitations** is set by License Level
and Toolbox (for automation) is limited in geoprocessing 
Features need to be converted to Representation before applying 
http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=An_overview_of_the_Representation_Management_toolset